# react bootstrap Configuration Error In webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

have same issues withe web pack project can you please help me to resolve that one. I didn't use react-scripts because it's web pack project. i have migrated react-bootstrap 1.6.4 to 2.1.1
Current Version: 2.1.1

the errors are:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/SplitButton.js Module
> parse failed: Unexpected token (101:2) You may need an appropriate
> loader to handle this file type. | renderMenuOnMount, |
> rootCloseEvent, | ...props | }, ref) => /#PURE/_jsxs(Dropdown, { |
> ref: ref, @ ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 67:0-55 @
> ./src/containers/Layout.jsx @ ./src/routes/index.jsx @
> ./src/containers/App.jsx @ ./src/index.jsx @ multi
> (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server
> react-hot-loader/patch babel-polyfill whatwg-fetch ./src/index.jsx

the issue did not occur in react-bootstrap@2.0.0-alpha.1

Comment: add configuration webpack

Comment: @A.R.SEIF can you please help me to configure that one or else can you share me the reference url

Comment: how migrate react-bootstrap